# Как просуммировать значения только для уникальных ID в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить таблицу

Как получить такую таблицу, уникальную по имэйлам и с суммой, уникальной по ID

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для подсчета Number of Unique Ids я могу использовать Count (distinct ID), а как посчитать сумму без дублей правильно? 
Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Смотрите "Group By" и агрегатную функцию Sum(). Подобные вопросы уже много раз "обсосаны" на этом форуме - воспользуйтесь поиском. Нельзя с такими девственно-чистыми мозгами от знаний приходить на форум.

Comment: Если я просто делаю Group By Email, в тотал Amount я получу 700, а не 600 (айдишники я не вывожу и соответственно не группирую по ним). На самом деле не очевидно как избавиться от дублей в сумме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select email, count(*) u_id, sum(amount) qty from
(select distinct email, id, amount from t) X
group by email;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.